# Laravel passport creating a oauth_client with userid not with php artisan passport:client --password

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am new Laravel Passport and i want to create a oauth_client with a user_id, now in the table `oauth_clients` is the user_id null.

I want to login and get the oauth_clients credentials by user_id.

How can i create a oauth client based on a `user_id` so **not** with `php artisan passport:client --password` but with a endpoint.

I hope someone can help me how to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ClientRepository::class`.

#### Personal access client

```php
use Laravel\Passport\ClientRepository;

(new ClientRepository)->createPersonalAccessClient($userId, $name, $redirect);
```

#### Password grant client

```php
use Laravel\Passport\ClientRepository;

(new ClientRepository)->createPasswordGrantClient($userId, $name, $redirect);
```

---

Or from `Passport::class`

```php
Passport::client()->forceFill([
    'user_id'                => $userId,
    'name'                   => $name,
    'secret'                 => ($confidential || $personalAccess) ? Str::random(40) : null,
    'redirect'               => $redirect,
    'personal_access_client' => $personalAccess,
    'password_client'        => $password,
    'revoked'                => false,
]);
```